# How can I use IntelliJ IDEA to "group" data source connections into arbitrary categories?

Tags: intellij-idea

The place I'm currently working at has gone all in the micro-services approach.  There are a hundred or so services, with many having their own database, each requiring a different data source with different connection details.
Then there's multiple environments (local development, CI, SIT, UAT, etc.)

I don't have connections for each one of those but I do have, so far, about 30 connections in my database tool window, spread across a few of those environments (mostly local and CI, but a few from other environments).

I'd like to start organising/grouping those connections (probably by environment, but a different categorisation might make more sense later) - I've more than once been jumping around between different databases and jumped into the DB for the right service, but in the wrong environment.

I've looked at the tool window buttons, and the right-click menu - but nothing there seems to be relevant to grouping the datasource nodes in the tool window.

My current workaround is to make sure each connection description starts with a prefix that identifies the environment - `_local svc-blah`, `CI svc-blah`, etc.  IDEA sorts these alphabetically, so the connections for the same environment tend to stay together (note the underbar on the beginning of the local connections so they are at the top of the list).  This works ok, but if IDEA has a grouping mechanism it would presumably have some expand/collapse functionality, which would help me out too.

The question: How can I use IntelliJ IDEA to "group" data source connections into arbitrary categories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it can be grouped. Just select one and hit F6 - you will be prompted to enter group name and then you will see it like a 'folder' in tree, where you can drag'n'drop others.